# Spherical Area Lights do not match reference

Tags: opengl, shaders, lighting

So I'm adding spherical area lights to my application, and comparing my results with mitsuba, I am getting some differences *(left is my approach, right is mitsuba - a pathtraced reference)*:

[image: Comparison]

What I am mainly noticing is that:

1. The specular is way too bright for roughness values over 0.5
2. The specular shape gets "flat" (Left-mine, Right-mitsuba, noise
   caused by low sample count):

[image: Flat Specular]

---

I am using the closest point approximation and the normalization term proposed in [Real Shading in UE4](http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/s2013-shading-course/karis/s2013_pbs_epic_slides.pdf), that is: `(radius / (distance * 2.0) + alpha)²`

I believe issue 1) could be an issue with my normalization term, however I think issue 2) might probably be an issue with the closest point approximation?

---

**Is this kind of inaccuracy expected with the approximations I use, and if so, are there better approximations?**

Comment: For context could you show us the rest of your Implementation please.

Comment: you haven't provided us enough code for us to actually help you.